# Firebase In app Messaging Not Working in Production

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am Using this [url](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=android#add_the_sdk_to_your_project) for Firebase In app Messaging integration into android application, But Issue is in-app-messaging is working fine in Test on Device using (Instance Id)(In Test Scenario) but it is not working in normal case. I am unable to see the Campaign output (Result) in production mode

Comment: I have a similar problem as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65655110/why-are-my-firebase-in-app-messages-unreliable-in-production

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Anyone find a solution?